# XCode Copy Files build phase skips files sometimes

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, build-process, header-files

I followed this excellent tutorial to set up to build a framework I'm building for an iOS app.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/

I have everything working pretty well except for one little detail.  Sometimes, it can take several attempts at building the project before all the header files are copied into the final framework.

Occasionally I'll hit "Build" and the Headers folder for the framework is completely empty at the end.  Sometimes it will have 90% of the headers, but not all.  Once in a while I get lucky and they all seem to be there.

What would cause this and how do I correct it?

Update:
So far my only solution is to just keep rebuilding the framework and eventually it copies all the headers the way I expect it to.  Still looking for a better answer though.

Comment: What I often do in situations like these is deleting the project's folder in Derived Data (~/Library/Xcode/shared/Derived Data).

Comment: I've been doing that too.  It doesn't seem to have an effect in this case though.  At least not consistently.

Answer (score 0):

One of the **workaround** I use to get around this problem is dirty (i.e. double-click open file, press spacebar & delete key on keyboard and save/Cmd+s) all the 'add copy files' before I build (Cmd+B).

**Another workaround** - Build the project twice and on second build, the files get copied.

Anyone have real cause/solution of this issue?

Comment: I would like to try some scripting to do the above e.g. 'touch' shell command (Add a Run script phase before copy file phase)